# Replace given value in vector

Tags: r, replace

I'm looking for a function which will replace all occurrences of one value with another value.
For example I'd like to replace all zeros with ones.
I don't want to have to store the result in a variable, but want to be able to use the vector anonymously as part of a larger expression.

I know how to write a suitable function myself:

```
> vrepl <- function(haystack, needle, replacement) {
+   haystack[haystack == needle] <- replacement
+   return(haystack)
+ }
> 
> vrepl(c(3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 0), 0, 1)
[1] 3 2 1 1 4 1
```

But I'm wondering whether there is some standard function to do this job, preferrably from the `base` package, as an alternative from some other commonly used package. I believe that using such a standard will likely make my code more readable, and I won't have to redefine that function wherever I need it.

Comment: Is something like `as.numeric(gsub(0, 1, c(3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 0)))` useful?

Comment: `vec[vec==vec]<-replacement`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Perhaps `replace` is what you are looking for:

```
> x = c(3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 0)
> replace(x, x==0, 1)
[1] 3 2 1 1 4 1
```

Or, if you don't have `x` (any specific reason why not?):

```
replace(c(3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 0), c(3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 0)==0, 1)
```

Many people are familiar with `gsub`, so you can also try either of the following:

```
as.numeric(gsub(0, 1, x))
as.numeric(gsub(0, 1, c(3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 0)))
```

## Update

After reading the comments, perhaps `with` is an option:

```
with(data.frame(x = c(3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 0)), replace(x, x == 0, 1))
```

Comment: Remember that this doesn't change `x` unless reassigned.

Comment: The specific reason why not to name `x` is that the expression computing `x` might itself be rather long. And I want to avoid clobbering my namespace with too many variables. So I had hoped for a way to avoid having to name the vector, or having to duplicate its expression. `gsub` and its character intermediate doesn't feel right either, in terms of performance as well as precision, particularly when dealing with floating point numbers.

Comment: I definitely could and should use `replace` in my own `vrepl` implementation, unless someone will come up with an answer which obsoletes my own function altogether. So thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @MvG, what about: `with(data.frame(x = c(3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 0)), replace(x, x == 0, 1))`?

Answer (score 20):

Another simpler option is to do:

```
 > x = c(1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2)
 > x[x==1] <- 0
 > x
 [1] 0 0 2 4 5 2 0 3 2
```

Comment: This requires saving the intermediate result to a named variable, which I want to avoid, as I stated in my question.

Comment: @MvG: sorry, missed that part. Anyway it is much more maintainable to save it in a variable

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to do this is using base [`ifelse`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/ifelse.html), which is vectorized (there's also [`if_else`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/if_else.html) from dplyr that handles missing values). If the condition is satisfied, we use a replacement value, otherwise we use the original value.

```
v <- c(3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 0)
ifelse(v == 0, 1, v)
```

We can avoid a named variable by using a pipe.

```
c(3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 0) %>% ifelse(. == 0, 1, .)
```

A common task is to do multiple replacements. Instead of nested `ifelse` statements, we can use `case_when` from **dplyr**:

```
case_when(v == 0 ~ 1,
          v == 1 ~ 2,
          TRUE ~ v)
```

---

Old answer:

For factor or character vectors, we can use `revalue` from `plyr`:

```
> revalue(c("a", "b", "c"), c("b" = "B"))
[1] "a" "B" "c"
```

This has the advantage of only specifying the input vector once, so we can use a pipe like

```
x %>% revalue(c("b" = "B"))
```

Comment: I'll vote you up for using `plyr` in 2018 - must be hard living under a stone :p

Comment: @MSBerends since dplyr works (mainly) with dataframes I'm not aware of a dplyr solution

Answer (score 4):

If someone is looking for a `dplyr` alternative to `replace`, `case_match` is a simple variant to `case_when` that works on vectors. It is available since `1.1.0`.

```r
x = c(3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 0)
case_match(x, 0 ~ 1, .default = x)
#[1] 3 2 1 1 4 1
```

It can also work with multiple replacements:

```r
x = c(3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 0)
case_match(x, 
           c(0, 2, 4) ~ "even",
           c(1, 3) ~ "odd")
#[1] "odd"  "even" "odd"  "even" "even" "even"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ifelse` function would be a quick and easy way to do this.

Comment: I would have to give the same vector twice, once for the `test` argument, and once as one of the result arguments, right? Doesn't seem any easier than the `replace` call mrdwab suggested.

Comment: Correct, but you could save it in a temporary variable and just reference that twice.  `ifelse` and `replace` will both do the job.

Comment: +1 this is actually a lot better than the correct solution, because it gives the extra option of applying a function to the values. Thanks @Greg Snow!

Comment: It would be helpful to provide an example of use.

Answer (score 2):

To replace more than one number:

```
vec <- 1:10
replace(vec, vec== c(2,6), c(0,9)) #2 and 6 will be replaced by 0 and 9.
```

**Edit:**

for a continous series, you can do this `vec <- c(1:10); replace(vec, vec %in% c(2,6), c(0,9))` 
but for `vec <- c(1:10,2,2,2); replace(vec, vec %in% c(2,6), 0)` we can replace multiple values with one value.

Comment: >Warning message:
In replace(vec, vec == c(2, 6), c(0, 9)) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Answer (score 2):

Why the fuss?

```
replace(haystack, haystack %in% needles, replacements)
```

Demo:

```
haystack <- c("q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y")
needles <- c("q", "w")
replacements <- c("a", "z")

replace(haystack, haystack %in% needles, replacements)
#> [1] "a" "z" "e" "r" "t" "y"
```

Comment: Note this answer assumes needles and replacements are 1-to-1 (recycling vectors if necessary).

Comment: This depends on the sorting of `haystack`, `needles` and `replacements`, too. Switch the latter to `c("w", "q")` and `c("z", "a")` and `replace()` will produce nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace lot of values in single go, you can use 'library(car)'.

**Example**

```
library(car)

x <- rep(1:5,3)

xr <- recode(x, '3=1; 4=2')

x
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
xr
## [1] 1 2 1 2 5 1 2 1 2 5 1 2 1 2 5
```