# Replacing vector values

Tags: r, vector, replace, conditional-statements, gsub

I am having a big dataframe (dataset_n) consisting of several columns, each for a different variable.
I am concentrating now on the variables:

1. q32, i.e. net recalled wages
2. pgssyear, i.e. the year when a person was asked the question about the wages

I would like to create an additional column that would stand for the CPI in a given year (pgssyear), so that I can calculate real wages later on (dividing the q32 with the CPI column).

I tried the following:
- copying the pgssyear under a different name (creating a new vector with the name "year", but with the same contents) and replacing the first year: 1992 with 1 using "replace" hoping to be able to replace 1993 with e.g. 1.35, etc.:

```
attach(dataset_n)
dataset_n$year <- pgssyear
detach(dataset_n)
dataset_n$year
```

neither of the options:
    replace(dataset_n$year, dataset_n$year == 1992, 1)
    replace(dataset_n$year, dataset_n$year == "1992", 1)
    with(data.frame(dataset_n), replace(dataset_n$year, dataset_n$year == 1992, 1)))

worked for me. Each time I got the massage: "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

```
dataset_n$year[dataset_n$year==1992] <- 1
```

did not work either and I got the message:
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, dataset_n$year == 1992, value = c(NA, NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

I suspect that when creating the new vector the numeric data got treated as factors.

I tried also:
    as.numeric(gsub(1992, 1, dataset_n$year))
    as.numeric(gsub(1993, 1.35, dataset_n$year))

This time the values got replaced, but I failed to achieve it "all at once", which is what I need.

I have also run out of further ideas, so any help would be appreciated.
 The other threads I have seen and which might be related are:
[Replace given value in vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737193/replace-given-value-in-vector)
[Error in <my code> : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308367/error-in-my-code-object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this line work:

```
dataset_n$year[dataset_n$year==1992] <- 1
```

Convert your year vector to numeric from factor like this:

```
dataset_n$year <- as.numeric(as.character(dataset_n$year))
```

Comment: At first i got NAs instead, but after restarting R, it worked! Thank you. Any ideas about the other options welcome :)

Comment: @Asiack You could try them again after doing the conversion to numeric, they might work then as well.