# Remove fake negative value in R

Tags: r

I need to calculate the total amount for each user in the data set but the problem is even when the amount for the user is 0 it keeps subtracting and generating fake negative values(there can't be amount less then 0 its bug).

For every + or - there are real events. However, when the amount hits 0, no matter how many negative events appear the result should not go below 0, and if we have first 10 negative events like going to -1000 and after that we have one positive +200 and after that one negative -100, I need the final result to be 100.

Here is example, the final total amount for that user should be 200.

```
userdata <- read.table(text="
 ID  Amount UserID Date     Hour
 1   500    2      3/3/2018 0:00
 2  -200    2      3/4/2018 0:00
 3  -250    2      3/5/2018 0:00
 4  -500    2      3/8/2018 0:00
 5   100    2      3/8/2018 0:00
 6  -50     2      3/8/2018 0:00
 7   250    2      3/8/2018 0:00
 8  -100    2      3/8/2018 0:00
", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I need a way to correctly calculate that amounts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace given value in vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737193/replace-given-value-in-vector)

Comment: I was not specific enough, if there is amount that is bigger than 0 it should subtract as much as the operation cost to 0, not all negative operations are bugs.

Comment: If we set both the negative values in your example to zero, then the total is still 500, which is more than the 250 you say it should be. So are some of the positive values also inaccurate/false?

Comment: Where is the subtraction code? Can you post what you are doing, not just the end result?

Comment: @aksela I don't have the subtraction code, its not my server.For every + or - there are real events however when  the amount hits 0 no matter how many negative events appear the result should not go below 0 and if we have first 10 negative events like going to - 1000 and after that we have one positive + 200 and after one negative- 100 i need the filnal result to be 100.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand, but I can't answer while the question is on hold. If you can  amend your example with something like what you just wrote I can nominate it for being reopened.

Comment: @aksela is now good ?

Comment: I added another example data set with a bit more going on in it. Would I be correct if I said the final value in this case should be 200?

Comment: @aksela Yes, exactly thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think we can solve this with a recursive filter, a sort of conditional cumulative sum.

```
# Isolate the vector we're interested in and prepend a zero
y <- c(0, userdata$Amount)

# run a for loop
for (i in 2:length(y)) {   # For every position in the vector, 
    y[i] <- y[i-1] + y[i]  # add the previous to the present.
    if (y[i] < 0) {        # If the resulting sum is less than zero,
        y[i] <- 0          # replace it with zero
    }
}

# Or equivalent, but maybe a bit more elegant
for (i in 2:length(y)) { 
    y[i] <- max(c(0, y[i-1] + y[i]))
}

y[-1]
# [1] 500 300  50   0 100  50 300 200  

tail(y, 1)
# 200
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the total amount is computed by a cumulative sum which never becomes negative.

While [AkselA's *recursive filter*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53868092/3817004) computes the totals by looping over the elements of the vector, the approach below iteratively corrects the cumulative sum whenever it becomes negative. Note that the order of elements is important, e.g., time series.

```
nonneg_cumsum <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  y <- cumsum(x)
  repeat {
    i <- head(which(y < 0), 1L)
    if (length(i) < 1) return(y)
    y[i:n] <- y[i:n] - y[i]
  }
}

nonneg_cumsum(userdata$Amount)
```

> ```
> [1] 500 300  50   0 100  50 300 200
> ```

For comparison, here is the output of the regular `cumsum()` function:

```
cumsum(userdata$Amount)
```

> ```
> [1]  500  300   50 -450 -350 -400 -150 -250
> ```