# Creating a sequence of vector and replacing some elements

Tags: r

I want this as my desired vector

```
0,2,3,0,5,0,7,0,0
```

I used these commands but didnt succeed.

```
b <- c(1:9)
b
x <- replace(b,b==c(1,4,6,8,9),c(0,0,0,0,0)
x
g <- (gsub(c(1,4,6,8,9),c(0,0,0,0,0),b))
```

Saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737193/replace-given-value-in-vector) before applying these commands.

Comment: `replace(b, c(1,4,6,8,9), 0)`

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks . Can you tell me how did ''b=='' created problem there. And can you help me with gsub command as well?

Comment: If you want to replace numbers `gsub` isn't the right function.

Comment: Try: `b[b %in% c(1,4,6,8,9)] <- 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we are comparing `b` with the vector using `==` we are comparing elementwise so `b[1]` is compared with 1, `b[2]` is compared with 4 and so on. Since `length(c(1,4,6,8,9))` is shorter than `length(b)` those values are recycled to match the length of `b`.

```
b == c(1,4,6,8,9)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

> Warning message:
>   In b == c(1, 4, 6, 8, 9) :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

To compare multiple values we need `%in%`

```
b %in% c(1,4,6,8,9)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

so that we can use `replace` like

```
replace(b,b %in% c(1,4,6,8,9),c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
#[1] 0 2 3 0 5 0 7 0 0
```

However, `replace` can accept vector of positions so we can directly do

```
replace(b, c(1,4,6,8,9), 0)
#[1] 0 2 3 0 5 0 7 0 0
```